# How to catch js button onclick event by CefShap on WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, web, events, cefsharp

How can I intercept a js onClick on a button in an Html document that is running under WinForms with CefSharp browser controller so that C# code can intercept this event and do some actions already in .NET environment?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775 and https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#javascript-integration

Comment: I saw all videos, docs and wiki. I could not solve this problem, or I did not fully understand the issue of work. All manuals on Obsolete methods, and new ones are not painted in the documentation. I would like a specific code example of how I can intercept a key click event and that's it :).

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/commit/2febd683b9e9f08e19aab68b575bae8b349c0ba5 for a complete example,  this can be greatly simplified using the new PostMessage feature. Just saying you've seen all the docs/videos isn't helpful as I've got no idea what you've actually read, you need to provide links and show what you have tried already.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for the tip. This was very difficult, because this example is present only in this commit and it is not in the master branch (a specific example with a click), as well as a lot of water in it and it is difficult to understand what methods and their settings are related to this issue. In the end, I managed to organize monitoring of Click events and triggering C# code during this action, but it looks very complicated and the documentation does not reveal this point in any way.
In my opinion, such a complex implementation should be encapsulated, and users should be given..

Comment: ..simpler methods of working with clear function names. What does the JS code handler cost to create the OnClick func trigger?! Most users won't be able to write it themselves, especially without the avail-ty of available docs or the avail-ty of cleaner and simpler examples. I would also put this  gen. of complex js scripts in C# code, so that the user could only correctly bind the type names, and the rest will be done by encapsulated code from the library. Fortunately,this is an Opensrc product.Sorry for a lot of words, just this task was given to me a lot of blood,and I'm still under stress)

Comment: You are welcome to improve the documentation. Posting your own answer might also be helpful for others. What exactly would an encapsulation look like?  If you come up with something reusable we can look at adding some helper classes. The new PostMessage feature makes it quite trivial in reality.

Comment: Quite a few of your questions don't make sense,  no idea what you mean by  cost to create the OnClick func trigger. Provide a meaningful detailed answer to this question and that can be the basis of some improved documentation.

Comment: How's that answer coming along?

Answer (score 6):

For basic communication you can use [CefSharp.PostMessage(message);](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775) in Javascript to send a message to .Net which triggers the [browser.JavascriptMessageReceived](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/E_CefSharp_IWebBrowser_JavascriptMessageReceived.htm) event.

```cs
// After your ChromiumWebBrowser instance has been instantiated (for WPF directly after `InitializeComponent();` in the control constructor).
// Subscribe to the following events
browser.JavascriptMessageReceived += OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived;
browser.FrameLoadEnd += OnFrameLoadEnd;

public void OnFrameLoadEnd (object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Frame.IsMain)
  {
    //In the main frame we inject some javascript that's run on mouseUp
    //You can hook any javascript event you like.
    browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"
      document.body.onmouseup = function()
      {
        //CefSharp.PostMessage can be used to communicate between the browser
        //and .Net, in this case we pass a simple string,
        //complex objects are supported, passing a reference to Javascript methods
        //is also supported.
        //See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775#issuecomment-498454221 for details
        CefSharp.PostMessage(window.getSelection().toString());
      }
    ");
  }
}

private void OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var windowSelection = (string)e.Message;
    //DO SOMETHING WITH THIS MESSAGE
    //This event is called on a CEF Thread, to access your UI thread
    //use Control.BeginInvoke/Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
}
```

Comment: Direct excerpt from https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent please check there for any further improvements. Further improvements are welcome, making as `community wiki` so others can contribute to this answer.